# Modification of partition function in quick sort algorithm

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

Given below is my implementation of quick sort for an assignment. The partition function is expected to divide a list into three parts. One having elements less than the pivot, one having elements equal to pivot and one having elements greater than pivot. It should then return the start and end indices of the part of the list containing elements equal to the pivot. I have written the following code but each time I execute the same code, I get different arrays as the final output. Please help.

```
import random
def random_sort(A,p,r):
  if p<r:
    i =random.randint(p,r)
    temp=A[r]
    A[r]=A[i]
    A[i]=temp
    q,t=partition(A,p,r)
    print(q,t)
    random_sort(A,p,q-1)
    random_sort(A,t+1,r)
  return A
def partition(A,p,r):
  x=A[r]
  i=p-1
  k=p-1
  for j in range(p,r):
    if A[j]<=x:
      i+=1
      temp = A[i]
      A[i]=A[j]
      A[j]=temp
  for j in range(p,i):
    if A[j]<x:
      k+=1
      temp=A[k]
      A[k]=A[j]
      A[j]=temp
    temp=A[i+1]
    A[i+1]=A[r]
    A[r]=temp
  return k+1,i+1
A=[1,2,9,5,2]
p=0
r=len(A)-1 
a=random_sort(A,p,r)
print(a)
```

Sample failing output:

```
(3, 4)
(0, 0)
(1, 2)
[2, 1, 2, 5, 9]
```

Sample succeeding output:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 3)
[1, 2, 2, 9, 5]
```

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what you think is the incorrect output?

Comment: What is being input into your functions? I can't tell what is being mapped to which variable. Thanks